# Showing $\int_{0}^{1}x^s[-\ln(x)]^t\cdot{1+x+x^2+\cdots x^k\over 1+x^{-1}+x^{-2}+\cdots+x^{-k}}dx={t!\over (1+s+k)^{t+1}}$

Tags: integration

Integrate

> $$I=\int_{0}^{1}x^s[-\ln(x)]^t\cdot{1+x+x^2+\cdots x^k\over 1+x^{-1}+x^{-2}+\cdots+x^{-k}}dx={t!\over (1+s+k)^{t+1}}\tag1$$

Recall

$$1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^n={x^{n+1}-1\over x-1}$$

Substitute into (1)

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^s[-\ln(x)]^t{x^{k+1}-1 \over x^{-(k+1)}-1}\cdot{x^{-1}-1\over x-1}dx={t!\over (1+s+k)^{t+1}}\tag2$$

$${x^{k+1}-1 \over x^{-(k+1)}-1}\cdot{x^{-1}-1\over x-1}dx=x^k$$

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+s}[-\ln(x)]^tdx={t!\over (1+s+k)^{t+1}}\tag3$$

Substitution

$u=-\ln(x)\rightarrow xdu=-dx$ And $x=e^{-u}$

$x=1\rightarrow u=0$ and $x=0 \rightarrow u=-\infty$

Substitute back into (3)

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}u^te^{-(s+k+1)u}du={t!\over (1+s+k)^{t+1}}\tag4$$

Apply Laplace transform to (4)

Recall Laplace transform $\int_{0}^{\infty}u^te^{-mu}du={t!\over m^{t+1}}$

$m=1+s+k$

$$I={t!\over (1+s+k)^{t+1}}\tag5$$

Anyone with another easy-quick method to tackle I?

Comment: Your method is quick! I think it is rather $k$ in $(2)$, not $n$.

Comment: (+1) U can still show me another method, I just want to learn from it. Thank

Comment: Isn't $\dfrac{1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^k}{1+x^{-1}+x^{-2}+\cdots+x^{-k}}=x^k$? That makes the integrand substantially clearer.

Comment: @Semiclassical The OP wanted to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+s}\log(x)^t\,dx = \frac{d^t}{dk^t}\int_{0}^{1}x^{k+s}\,dx=\frac{d^t}{dk^t}\left(\frac{1}{k+s+1}\right)=\frac{(-1)^t t!}{(k+s+1)^{t+1}}. \tag{1}$$

Answer (score 1):

let $x=e^{-u}$ then 
$$\int_{0}^{1}x^{s+k}(-\ln x)^t dx= \int_{+\infty}^{0}{(e^{-u})}^{s+k}\,u^t(-e^{-u} )=\int_{0}^{+\infty} u^t e^{-(s+k+1)u}du=\frac{\Gamma(t+1)}{(s+k+1)^{t+1}}$$